# zen coding - css syntax/ style attribute

Tags: html, css, emmet

I can't find the syntax about adding CSS properties using zen coding. Maybe I have overlooked the zen-cheat-sheet.

For example, how can I shorten the following:

```
<div style="background-color: red; float: right;"></div>
```

Comment: note: I have rewritten the example, because I would like to know how about more properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is full documentation on css property for zen coding way

See [this](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/wiki/ZenCSSPropertiesEn)

Your code for above html will be like this  :

**EDIT :**

```
div[style=background-color:red;float:right;]
```

Comment: I have tested it, but does not work. (notepad ++) The result is: <div style="bgc:red;fl:r"></div>

Comment: well, this works, but Its not too much shorter unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.red_fl_right
```

Would give it the class that the CSS could then define.
From there, you could write this in the CSS file:

```
red_fl_right{        
    bg
    fl:r
}
```

After expanding both lines, you can add the "red" to the bg value;